# C# deserialize json array in code behind.

Tags: c#, json

I have a json array like below :

```
{"division_ids":"[\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"]","particular_settings":"{\"sel_taxonomy\":\"\",\"particular_amount\":\"\",\"exclude_group\":null,\"discount_group_id\":\"-Select Group-\",\"discount_amount\":\"\",\"from_date\":\"\",\"to_date\":\"\"}"}
```

How do I deserialize it into two arrays one having 'division_ids' and other as 'particular settings'

Answer (score 0):

[Json.net library](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) allow you to deserialize object.

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse("your json string");
dynamic divisionIds = json.division_ids;
dynamic particularSettings = json.particular_settings;

Console.WriteLine(divisionIds[0]); // Output : 2
```

Comment: Or you may use ServiceStack facilities which can be downloaded through Nuget. It has very powerful and optimized ways on deserializing objects

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(yourJson);
var divList = jObject["division_ids"].ToObject<List<string>>();
var particularSettingList = jObject["particular_settings"].ToObject<List<string>>();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery and $.parseJSON.  I put together an example below.  Note that I had to make two changes to the json for this to work:  `"[\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"]"` becomes `[\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"]` and remove the double quotes around the second array, `"particular_settings":"{\"` becomes `"particular_settings":{\"` (remove the corresponding end quote too).

```
<script>

    function parseJson() {

       var myjson = '{"division_ids":[\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"],"particular_settings":{\"sel_taxonomy\":\"test",\"particular_amount\":\"\",\"exclude_group\":null,\"discount_group_id\":\"-Select Group-\",\"discount_amount\":\"\",\"from_date\":\"\",\"to_date\":\"\"}}';

        var obj = $.parseJSON( myjson );
        alert(obj.division_ids);
        alert(obj.particular_settings.sel_taxonomy);            

    }

</script>
```

Comment: This is a C# question and your answer is in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I read the question and not the title of the question.